# Why can't I print this array in F#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, f#

I have this list in C#:

```
List<string> words = new List<string> { "how", "are", "you" };
```

I can easily print the content of the list with:

```
foreach(string word in words)
   Debug.WriteLine(word);
```

Now I want to do the same in F# (I understand from over [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-2) that a `List<T>` is similar to a ResizeArray):

```ml
let words = ResizeArray<string>()
words.Add("how")
words.Add("are")
words.Add("you")

for word in words do
    Debug.WriteLine(sprintf "%s" word)
```

Now the problem is, that in the for-loop `word` becomes null. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
Here is the full code. I have changed it to printf as suggested. Unfortunately I still get null in word when inside the for-loop:

```ml
let myFunction =
    let words = ResizeArray<string>()
    words.Add("how")
    words.Add("are")
    words.Add("you")

    for word in words do
        printf "%s" word // <-- word becomes null
    words

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    ignore myFunction
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: Are you doing this in FSI?  FSI doesn't have access to the debug I think, so the output gets lost.  Do it in a console app and you should see the same result as the C# one.

Comment: Thanks, but I am doing it in a console application. Please see my EDIT update.

Comment: ...works for me.  Side point, your `myFunction` is not a function.  It should be `let myFunction() =` with the parens, if you want it to be a function.  The way you have it, it's just a global variable that gets instantiated during program initialization.

Comment: @brinch, ResizeArray doesn't a functional style. Why you don't want to write it this way: let myFunction =
    let words = [ "how"; "are"; "you" ]
    words |> List.iter(fun x-> printf "%s" x) Link: http://ideone.com/Z1nBrL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is due to the lazy evaluating nature of F#. So, `word` is not actually assigned till it is used by the `printf` statement, and hence you cannot see the value in the debugger.

If you add another statement in your loop and set a breakpoint there, you will see the value of assigned value of `word`. See the snippet below -

```ml
let myFunction =
let words = ResizeArray<string>()
words.Add("how")
words.Add("are")
words.Add("you")

for word in words do
    printf "%s" word // 
    printf "%s" word // <-- SET A BREAKPOINT HERE AND VERIFY THE VALUE OF 'word'

words
```

Comment: Yes, that seemed to make the difference, as 'word' now contains a value. Is there a way to get around this lazy evaluation, so printf won't have to be repeated twice to work?

Comment: @brinch, the code *works*. You just can't see the value when you hit  it with a breakpoint. **This code is working fine**.

Comment: I agree with @CBauer, your code works fine, whether you can see the value in the debugger is a moot point. After all, the program should primarily run and work outside the debugger! Are you not seeing the output of printf in your console?

Answer (score 5):

I understand you want your code to look like C#. But F# is a functional language (not strictly, but that's main paradigm) and in these features lies the power of the language. First your collection. A more idiomatic type is a List. It's immutable which is one of the functional features of the language.

```ml
let words = ["how"; "are"; "you"]
```

Since it's immutable you expand it by creating a new collection. You can append an item at the beginning:

```ml
let moreWords = "Hello" :: words
```

or join one list with another one:

```ml
let evenMore = moreWords @ ["I"; "am"; "fine"]
```

Then iterating. For loop is purely imperative construct. Since we switched to a functional collection use one of the built-in List functions to iterate:

```ml
let prnt lst = lst |> List.iter (fun x -> printfn "%s" x)
```

This takes a list. Iterates it item by item. And executes the `(fun x -> printfn "%s" x)` function on each item.

Or you can play a bit and write your own function to go through all the elements and execute a function on each of them. One approach would be to use recursion and list matching:

```ml
let rec loopFn lst fn =
    match lst with
    | [] -> fn
    | head::tail ->
        fn head
        loopFn tail fn
```

This funciton takes a list and another function as arguments. Matches the list. If it's empty (`| []`) - performs the function. Otherwise splits the list to head and the rest (`head::tail`) executes the function on the `head` (`fn head`) and loops further on the remaining items (`loopFn tail fn`).

To print the items pass to the function the list of words and a print function:

```ml
loopFn words (fun x -> printfn "%s" x)
```

or since `printfn` is a function itself you can simplify the call a bit:

```ml
loopFn words (printfn "%s")
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```ml
for word in words do
    printf "%s" word
```

But if you really want debug output, are you loading the system.diagnostics namespace?

```ml
open System.Diagnostics

(Your code)
```

This worked for me without loading the namespace:

```ml
for word in words do
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(sprintf "%s" word)
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me. The word variable becomes null when inside the for-loop.

Comment: I put up three things that worked for me after copying and pasting your code into a new F# console project file.

Comment: If you changed to printf, then you should run the program using Ctrl+F5, which will keep the console window open long enough for you to see the output.

Comment: @brinch, how do you know that `word` is `null`?

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin, I know because I have placed a debugging breakpoint in the code, and when I step into the for-loop, I can see that the variable (word) is null.

Comment: @brinch are you running it with ctrl f5 or not?

Comment: @brinch, that's what I suspected. Debugger is not a reliable source of information about what is really going on in the code, especially if the code has been optimized. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30205130/function-argument-is-null-even-though-a-non-null-argument-is-passed/30205758#30205758